# PHPMailer not work in yahoo and hotmail

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an email using phpmailer, it works fine when I send to gmail but when i send to yahoo, hotmail and so on its not works. 
Here is my code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$email->IsSMTP();
$email->Host = "smtp.yahoo.com";
$email->SMTPAuth = true;
$email->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$email-> Port = 465;
$email->Username   = "username";
$email->Password   = "*******";
$email->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->From = 'anonymous@domain.fr';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->AddAddress('test@yahoo.com');
$mail->AddReplyTo('no-reply@domain.fr');
$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $mail_msg;
if ( $email->send() ){

    echo "success";
}
else {
    echo "555 " .$email->ErrorInfo;

}
```

Comment: for gmail what details you used?only change `AddAddress,AddReplyTo,subject,body`. don't change other settings if you are on same server

Answer (score 0):

Some basic reading of the docs and example code would help. You can't use explicit TLS (`SMTPSecure = 'tls'`) on a port expecting implicit TLS (`Port = 465`). Set `Port = 587`.

Of course you also need to have a working login for each service that you connect to, but the debug output will tell you if you've got that wrong.